# in R: How do I rank each individual data frame in a list of data frames?

Tags: r

I've simplified my problem conceptually as follows.  I have a list (mylist) comprised of two data frames. I know how to reorder them both (say, on the 4th and 1st variable) using lapply:

```
mylist<-lapply(mylist, function(x) x[order(x[,4],x[,1]),])
```

Now I am trying to use lapply() and rank() to add a 5th column to each dataframe in the list, and populate the column with the rank (the rank within that dataframe, on the 4th variable say).

Ive tried dozens of permutations of this

```
mylist[,5]<-lapply(mylist, function(x) rank(x[,4], ties.method="first"))
```

nothing works right. Help!  Thanks

```
> mylist
[[1]]
a b c d
1 1 4 7 A
2 2 5 8 A
3 3 6 9 B

[[2]]
a b c d
1 9 6 3 A
2 8 5 2 A
3 7 4 1 B
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it couldn't be:

```
  mylist[,5]<-lapply(mylist, function(x) rank(x[,4], ties.method="first"))
```

...  because `mylist[,5]` doesn't make any sense. `mylist` you said was a two element list so it really didn't even have columns. So you need to loop over the elements and add the column to them individually:

```
 mylist <-lapply(mylist, function(x) { rl <- rank( x[,4], ties.method="first")
                                      x <- cbind( x, rl=rl) 
                                      x [ order(x['rl']) , ] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `lapply` returns the output of `rank` which is a vector. You need to append a column to each `data.frame` then return the `data.frame`

```
mylist <- list(data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rpois(5, 3)), data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rpois(5, 3)) )
mylist
## [[1]]
##             a b
## 1 -1.31730854 4
## 2  0.04395243 1
## 3  0.15370905 0
## 4 -0.77556501 4
## 5  1.12879380 4
## 
## [[2]]
##             a b
## 1 -0.96314478 3
## 2 -0.54824004 6
## 3  0.34943917 1
## 4 -0.07077913 0
## 5  1.10519356 3

lapply(mylist, function(x) { x$c <- rank(x$b); x })
## [[1]]
##             a b c
## 1 -1.31730854 4 4
## 2  0.04395243 1 2
## 3  0.15370905 0 1
## 4 -0.77556501 4 4
## 5  1.12879380 4 4
## 
## [[2]]
##             a b   c
## 1 -0.96314478 3 3.5
## 2 -0.54824004 6 5.0
## 3  0.34943917 1 2.0
## 4 -0.07077913 0 1.0
## 5  1.10519356 3 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data provided by @JakeBurkhead, you can simply use `transform`

```
set.seed(123)
mylist <- list(data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rpois(5, 3)),
               data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rpois(5, 3)) )
lapply(mylist, transform, c = rank(b, ties.method = "first"))
## [[1]]
##           a b c
## 1 -0.560476 6 5
## 2 -0.230177 3 2
## 3  1.558708 4 4
## 4  0.070508 3 3
## 5  0.129288 1 1

## [[2]]
##          a b c
## 1  1.28055 4 5
## 2 -1.72727 3 3
## 3  1.69018 3 4
## 4  0.50381 2 2
## 5  2.52834 1 1
```